# what is the difference of install r package in tow commands?

Tags: r, package

When I install the packages in R, sometimes it is used by `devtools::install_github()`. other times it is used by `install.packages()`.
Could I ask what is the essential difference between them?

Answer (score 1):

R's official repository for packages is located on CRAN (Comprehensive R Archive Network). The process of publishing a package there is very strict and is reachable via `install.packages()`. For the most part, binary packages (opposed to source code, which is not "properly translated" yet) are available and no additional tools need to be present for proper installation (see next paragraph).

GitHub is one of many webservices that offers repositories for code, incl. R code. Author can upload her or his package and if everything is in its place, the user can install a package from source via `devtools::install_github()`. This means you need to have a proper toolchain installed (also a distributoin of LaTeX). In Windows, this means [Rtools](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/). Linux based OS are likely to be shipped with most of the necessary tools.

Comment: Linux is not always necessary. Vignettes for example could be built in HTML or just not build at all.

Comment: Thanks for your answer very much! Such a clear explanation.